# No user_config.py

Tags: python, pywikibot

We have an internal wiki and I want to use pywikibot to get some data from it. Installed it from pip but when I import it I get:

```
>>> import pywikibot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pywikibot/__init__.py",
line 25, in <module>
from pywikibot.bot import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pywikibot/bot.py", line
105, in <module>
    from pywikibot import config2 as config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pywikibot/config2.py",
line 373, in <module>
    base_dir = get_base_dir()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pywikibot/config2.py",
line 367, in get_base_dir
    raise RuntimeError(exc_text)

RuntimeError: No user-config.py found in directory '/vagrant'.
```

Looking here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/Installation#Configure_Pywikibot

I see a reference to pwb.py, but that does not exist in
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pywikibot.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Installing `pywikibot` from `pip` currently only installs the library part. The `pwb.py` and related console scripts are not included in the PyPI package. That means that you'll need to create the `user-config.py` manually or download the scripts in some other way.
I believe most `pywikibot` users just clone the git repo. The general process would be something like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/wikimedia/pywikibot.git --depth 1
python3 -m pip install -U setuptools
python3 -m pip install -e pywikibot/
cd pywikibot/
python3 pwb.py generate_family_file.py https://url.to.your/wiki/api.php? mywikiname
python3 pwb.py generate_user_files.py
# follow the prompts
```

Comment: Is the format of the config file defined somewhere?

Comment: Since you've mentioned that it's an internal wiki,  it's not just the `user-config.py`, you'll also need a family file (the `generate_family_file.py` above does that for you). I'm saying you might have a hard time configuring them all correctly, but see: https://github.com/wikimedia/pywikibot/blob/master/user-config.py.sample

Comment: @LarryMartell Also https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/user-config.py has more in-depth instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this was very helpful. A couple more questions:
1. Is there any way to login with MFA? Our wiki requires either choosing a number from an authenticator app or using a userid and password and then entering a code which was texted.
2. Is there a way to get all pages within a category?

Comment: These can be separate SO questions, but AFAK `pywikibot` currently only supports [BotPassword](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login#Method_1._login) and [OAuthen](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OAuth), [clientlogin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login#Method_2._clientlogin) works only if MFA is not active :( Once the setup is complete getting pages within a category would be easy: `Category(Site(), 'title').members()`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding generate_family_file is in active development:
https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/c/pywikibot/core/+/634544

The other two script will follow later I guess.